# How do I set the width of a Tkinter.Text widget scrollbar?

Tags: python, python-3.x, tkinter

I'm trying to create a Tkinter `Text` widget with a `Scrollbar`. This is working all fine, except I want the `Scrollbar` to have a `width` of *12 pixels*, instead of the default value of *16 pixels*. On the documentation online, it states that width is indeed an option you can set. So what am I doing wrong? Below is the code I have tried using.

```
from tkinter import *

root = Tk()
textBox = Text(root, bd=0, font=('Courier New', 8), width=100, height=25, wrap=NONE)
textVerticalScroll = Scrollbar(root, width=12)
textBox.configure(yscrollcommand=textVerticalScroll.set)
textBox.pack(side=LEFT, fill=BOTH, expand=True)
textVerticalScroll.pack(side=RIGHT, fill=Y)
```

Comment: What platform? I think you can only change the width on non-windows, non-osx machines. Such is the price we pay for native widgets.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Your code works, see the screenshots:

width=5:

[image]

width=55:

[image]

I guess this is os related. I'm using Ubuntu 14.04 x64 and python 3.4. Maybe on windows or mac the width is fixed and controlled by os. Or tk implementation for these OSs does not change it or work properly.

Comment: Thanks for your response. I see that the Operating System does set some restrictions.